# Return True if an array has a 2 directly next to another 2

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, python-3.x

Given an array of ints, return True if the array contains a 2 next to a 2 somewhere.

has22([1, 2, 2]) → True

has22([1, 2, 1, 2]) → False

has22([2, 1, 2]) → False

My attempt at this was:

```
def has22(nums):
    if 2 in nums:
        if (nums[nums.index(2) + 1] == 2):
            return True
        elif (nums[nums.index(2) - 1] == 2):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Which results in `Error: list index out of range`. If anyone can explain why this is happening that'd be appreciated.

Comment: What if 2 is the first or last number? It will be out of bounds...

Comment: Yea I guess I assumed that if it results in the out of bounds it would just move onto the next if else statement. Any thought on how I could achieve that?

Comment: You can wrap you conditionals in a `try: ... except IndexError: pass` to ignore the exception.

Answer (score 2):

First, [`pairwise()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). And then:

```
any(x == y == 2 for (x, y) in pairwise(seq))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the [pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) idea, and here is other without importing anything

```
any( seq[i-1] == seq[i] == 2 for i in range(1,len(seq)) )
```

---

The problem with your code is that not only will fail when 2 is the first or last element, it also will fail when the pair of 2s is not the with the first 2 like for example [1,2,3,2,2] because `.index` only give you the first position of the first 2.

The solution is simple, ask for a index that you know will be there, as show in the example above starting in 1 ask for all indexes and the previous one so in the first time you ask for index 0 and 1, then 1 and 2, and so on

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a small [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range):

```
any(a == b == 2 for a, b in zip(seq, seq[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Solution

```
def has22(a, i = 0):
  if(i < len(a) - 1):
    if(a[i] == 2 and a[i+1] == 2):
      return True
    return has22(a, i + 1)
  return False
```